# C# - Settings Reset when Application Filename is Changed

Tags: c#

I read other questions here stating to do `.Upgrade()` and use a StrongName but it hasn't done a single difference on my end.

`.Upgrade()` Code:

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.updateSettings) {
    Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
    Properties.Settings.Default.updateSettings = false;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Proof of StrongName being applied:

[image]

Yet as you can see, if I change the filename, it will go store settings in its own directory.

The issue here is people are renaming the .exe a lot and my updater stores the updated .exe next to it with appName-xxxx.exe (xxxx = 1.0.0.0 for ex)

So the .exe will almost always be renamed causing settings to be reset every time.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here would be to decouple the settings from the executable further than what the default framework-provided convention is. To solve this you'd have to create some sort of service completely separate from the application instance you have and manage your settings that way.

Another option would be to store the settings in a table in the database and tie that to the instance of the application being run (stored elsewhere) and use that to retrieve the application settings.

Which road you take depends on many things, only which you can know and judge best.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah I COULD do that, but id prefer not to. That's like saying I could hit my head off a wall to go to sleep, it works, but its not optimal.

Comment: looking at your folder names, are you working on a Universal Windows App? Your tags only say c#, a bit more context provided as to the problem at hand might help other to suggest better things.

Comment: No WinForms :).